# ¿Por qué "suizo" es un bollo especial?

Tags: etimología, significado, comida

El Diccionario de la Lengua indica que [un suizo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Yg1OhNZ) es, entre otras cosas, un "Bollo especial de harina, huevo y azúcar.", que no parece tener ninguna relación con los demás significados de la palabra.

¿Por qué "suizo" es un bollo especial? ¿Y qué tiene de especial?

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollo_suizo)

> El bollo suizo (a veces simplemente suizo) es un bollo tipo brioche elaborado en las pastelerías madrileñas. **Debe su nombre y su popularidad por haberse elaborado en el ya cerrado Café Suizo de Madrid**

Respecto a lo de "qué tiene de especial" (y un poco más sobre las historia del bollo y su nombre)

> El nombre originario dado a este tipo de bollo madrileño es el de bollo de leche y se servía como desayuno y merienda habitualmente en los cafés de finales del siglo XIX en Madrid. **La oferta tan exitosa que se hacía de él en Café Suizo** hizo que al principio se les denominase "bollos del suizo" y finalmente simplemente como «suizos».

No se indica por qué se hicieron tan populares, más allá de citar lo cuidado de su elaboración y una "promoción del producto" acertada.

Comment: Y Sor, para saber qué tienen de especial, habría que probar algunas de las recetas que hay en el internet.